# "Пермяк солёные уши"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "пермяк солёные уши"? Вроде как Пермь не на море, почему же тогда солёные?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Море тут ни при чем.
Выражение связано с существовавшими с XV соляными промыслами в Верхнекамье.
В Сети об этом масса источников, легко найдёте.